# Rightmove outcode url parameter for scraper

Tags: javascript, csv, screen-scraping, postal-code

I have an issue in trying to write a scraper for RightMove.

In a generic search like this:

http://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=OUTCODE^1891&insId=3&minBedrooms=2&maxBedrooms=2&displayPropertyType=houses&oldDisplayPropertyType=houses&googleAnalyticsChannel=buying

We have an OUTCODE parameter.
So an outcode is the begining of a UK postcode, for example OX17, but I cant tell where the number 1891 comes from. There is the possibility that rightmove have some propriatary system in place in order to stop scrapers, but there may be some database.

I have a CSV I downloaded from some 'official' website, but I dont remember where (sorry about that). The outcodes have a number but they dont corrolate to what I was expecting.

I also found this by mistake on google (I think it is the full version of the CSV I had) which is verry similar to what I was playing with.

https://github.com/craigfrancis/framework/blob/master/framework/0.1/library/class/nearest/outcode.csv

Thanks,
Joe

======================================================

So, turns out the nuber iterates from 1 to something (not sure yet).

1891 is OX17, 1890 is OX16 and so on.

I wrote a simple scraper which goes from location Ident 1 until there are no locations left and adds the to a Mongo Database... Will put everything on a GitHub Repo when it is done. I will also export the db as JSON for anyone who wants it.

Tah!

Comment: Did you manager to work it out?

Comment: https://github.com/ISNIT0/Rightmove-Scrapers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of Rightmove outcodes in json format:

pastebin.com/8nX5JT1q

to convert to csv use a JSON to csv converter tool

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post link-only answers but summarize the linked content or its relevant parts a little. A link may become invalid or outdated and in that case, your answer would be useless in the future. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.